# iterate json and find particular key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, typescript

- I am new to js.
- I am trying to iterate json structure.
- when I see isDefault: true, I need to show as a default name.
- but right now I am hard coding in the value in my js code.
- can you  tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below.

```or-tag-here
data.downlinkmoons =[{Lion: 237, birds: "Animal Sports Bay Area", fish: 1, isDefault: true, wire: ""},
                        {Lion: 238, birds: "Animal Sports California", fish: 1, wire: ""},
                        {Lion: 239, birds: "Animal Sports Washington", fish: 1, wire: ""},
                        {Lion: 240, birds: "Animal Sports Philadelphia", fish: 1, wire: ""}]


playOutside(data: any) {
        let that = this;
        let tempObj = {};
        //tempObj['Lion'] = 237;
        tempObj['Lion'] = data.downlinkmoons[0].Lion;
        tempObj['birds'] = 'Animal Sports Bay Area';
        // tempObj['Lion'] = data.selectedLion;
        // tempObj['birds'] = data.selectedbirds;
        this.moonTempArray = [];
        this.moonTempArray.push(tempObj);
        let moonsdata = data.downlinkmoons;
        let moonsDataList = this.moonTempArray;
        let selectedmoon = moonsdata.find(elem => elem.Lion == 237);
        this.downlinkBulkUpdateVal.Lion = 237;
        // let selectedmoon = moonsdata.find(elem => elem.Lion == data.selectedLion);
        // this.bulkCreateVal.Lion = data.selectedLion;
        this.selectedmoonArr = selectedmoon;
        this.moonCarousel.setmoonData(moonsdata, moonsDataList, 237);
        //this.moonCarousel.setmoonData(moonsdata, moonsDataList, data.selectedLion);
        $("#moonCarouselLabel .moonHint").css("display", "none");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#unSelectedmoonsLogoBox1 .currentNwLogo").bind("click", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                that.singleSelection(data, e);
            });
        }, 100);
    }
```

Comment: Read about `Object.keys` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey hi...I looked at the link...can you update in my code snippet...its so confusing :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.prototype.find()` function:

```
var downlinkmoons =[{Lion: 237, birds: "Animal Sports Bay Area", fish: 1, isDefault: true, wire: ""},
                        {Lion: 238, birds: "Animal Sports California", fish: 1, wire: ""},
                        {Lion: 239, birds: "Animal Sports Washington", fish: 1, wire: ""},
                        {Lion: 240, birds: "Animal Sports Philadelphia", fish: 1, wire: ""}];

function getDefault(downlinkmoons){                                                
    return downlinkmoons.find((elem) => { return elem.isDefault; });                 
}

console.log(getDefault(downlinkmoons))
```

More info about Array.prototype.find is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: hi...thanks for your reply...but if I use same code inside playOutside method its data.find is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```js
var downlinkmoons =[{Lion: 237, birds: "Animal Sports Bay Area", fish: 1, isDefault: true, wire: ""},
                        {Lion: 238, birds: "Animal Sports California", fish: 1, wire: ""},
                        {Lion: 239, birds: "Animal Sports Washington", fish: 1, wire: ""},
                        {Lion: 240, birds: "Animal Sports Philadelphia", fish: 1, wire: ""}];
function getDefault(downlinkmoons){                                                
for(var i=0; i<downlinkmoons.length; i++){
     if(downlinkmoons[i].hasOwnProperty("isDefault"))
     { 
          if(downlinkmoons[i].isDefault)
             return downlinkmoons[i];
            
          break;
     }
     
}

}
console.log(getDefault(downlinkmoons))
```

To use it in your script Do the following

```
tempObj['Lion'] = getDefault(downlinkmoons).Lion
```

Comment: hi but how to pass dynamically inside playOutside method --->         tempObj['Lion'] = data.downlinkmoons[0].Lion;

Comment: wrap it in a function and assign the returned value to `tempObj['Lion']`

Comment: hi...thanks for your reply...but if I usesame code inside playOutside method its not working...can you tell me how to pass into playOutside method